# Get value of an expression in a custom html control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a custom html control that results in a select2 dropdown.
It works perfect on string, guid and int values, but not on Lists

the variable propertyValueString contains the value of a the property which is ok in most situations but not in lists (in my case List of Guid). It results in "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]", but should be a csv list of guid.

EDIT: Added signature and call added

Any idea how i can make it work for lists objects?

```
// Called by using
// Changed a bit, because of multiple overloads
// @Html.Select2DropdownFor(o => o.InTeamsUID).ToHtml("autocompleteUrl",null, new DropdownOptions {Multiple = true})

private readonly Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> _propertyExpression;    
public MvcHtmlString ToHtml(string url, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, DropdownOptions options)
    {
           var propertyName = _htmlHelper.NameFor(_propertyExpression).ToString();
        var propertyId = _htmlHelper.IdFor(_propertyExpression).ToString();
        var propertyValueString = _htmlHelper.ValueFor(_propertyExpression);

        if (propertyValueString != null)
            propertyValueString = new MvcHtmlString(propertyValueString.ToString());

        var container = new TagBuilder("span");
        if (!_htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(_htmlHelper.NameFor(_propertyExpression).ToString()))
            container.AddCssClass("has-error");

        var input = new TagBuilder("select")
            .Merge(htmlAttributes, true)
            .Class(_selectOptions.Multiple ? "enable-remote-multi-select" : "enable-remote-select")
            .Attribute("data-options-url", url)
            .Attribute("id", propertyId)
            .Attribute("name", propertyName)
            .Attribute("data-val", propertyValueString);
```

Comment: Show the signature of the method and how your using it in the view.

Comment: Done, see question, thx

Comment: Now its making even less sense. What is your `Select2DropdownFor()` method (and what is the point of your `ToHtml()` method when the `Select2DropdownFor()` method should have been generating the correct html anyway. And that is not the way to generate a `<select>` element - you do not get correct 2-way model binding, you do not get client side validation etc etc. What is the html that you actually trying to output with this?

Comment: It is a select that is generated with custom properties, where my javascript will recognize it and it will convert it to a select2 (js) control with autocompletion. It does automatically things that aren't necessary to repeat in every cshtml anymore. It works fine for single value datatypes.

Comment: Yes, and all you need to do is add attributes the the element generated by `_htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, .....` You should edit you question to show the desired html